# Windows 8 x64bit re-install unable to identify drives on HP Envy 4 1002tx

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, fedora, hp-laptop

I have an HP Envy 1002tx ultrabook [Full Spec: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c03342406 ] on which I used to have a Windows 8 x64 Pro dual booted with Fedora 18 x64. Recently my boot loader for windows started giving error which could not be corrected using the Repair USB. I used to get **0x000000f** error earlier.

So I went ahead and **formatted the C: partition[Earlier windows partition]** using gparted from Fedora. I also deleted the partition of the type **Microsoft Recovery Partition**. Now I am left with the following disk partitions with Fedora still working:

[image: Gparted Screenshot of my current drive partitions in Fedora 18 x64]

So, I later created a UEFI USB for Windows 8 x64 Pro [Fat32 partition] and booted using the UEFI USB. I am able to get to the screen where it says install windows. I click that and choose a fresh install. Now it is showing the partition screen but none of my partitions are listed.

It is giving the error **"We couldn't find any drives."**. Also, I downloaded the HP Envy drivers from the HP site: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4132&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5317852 and placed it in the USB drive under a folder drivers in the USB root.

Here is a screenshot of my USB directory:
[image]

I have already tried booting using the USB and using Shift + F10 and using the following commands:

**bootrec /RebuildBcd** - It gives the error couldn't find any windows partition.

Running **DISKPART> list drives** only shows the USB drive.

Is there any way, I can install the Windows 8 x64 Pro on my machine ?

Before deleting the MRP partition, I was getting the error "Required partitions are inaccessible for installation." when I was selecting **/dev/sda5 - 77 GB** partition for fresh install.

Comment: Fixed the Drives not found issue by putting drivers from intel site https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22787&ProdId=2101&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%208*&DownloadType=Drivers

And putting it in a folder in USB and loading drivers from there.

Comment: Update your question if you have solved part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the **Drives not found** issue by putting drivers from intel site https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22787&ProdId=2101&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%208

Put the files in a folder in USB and loading drivers from there during the Windows 8 installation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to run fixboot/fixmbr commands from the Repair your computer menu at installation screen. That will fix things.

Comment: Already done that very early. Doesn't solve the issue. I don't have any windows installation. So fixing MBR will not work either.